Отсутствует перевод в комментарии о дубликате
В комментарие о дубликате часть не переведена:


На traducir есть: https://ru.traducir.win/strings/20949

https://i.sstatic.net/YFZXpXWx.png а бывает, что даже не дописан текст...

Предложил перевод.

. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.


. Если вы уверены что это не так, нажмите [edit], дайте ясно понять, чем ваш вопрос отличается от дубликата и/или почему ответы на него не помогают решить вашу проблему.


Утвердил. Текущая сборка  rev 2024.11.8.18238
